# UISlider not sliding in prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9, uislider

**I have designed a prototype cell in a Storyboard's view controller, but unfortunately the `UISlider` in the cell is not sliding.**

**Note:-** Autolayout is enabled for this storyboard.

Design:-

[image]

**Here is code:-** to render the cell in `UITableview`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if(indexPath.row!=self.arrSelectRecipientsImages.count-1 )
    {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"selectReciptenceTabCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    }
    else
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"selectNearbyTabCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UISlider *sliderNearby = (UISlider *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:199];
        lblDistance = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:190];
        sliderNearby.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [sliderNearby setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NearbyCircle"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sliderNearby addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderNearbyAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  }
return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think `didSelectRow` touch delegate is conflicting with slider touch.

Comment: A slider should work in a table view, please describe the problem with more details.

Comment: The problem is very simple, on sliding the slider it's is not sliding.@A-Live

Comment: The problem must be indeed very simple, however your description is not sufficient to identify it. Even though identifying the problem in this case will mist likely provide an obvious solution, I suggest that you try to provide more details. The easiest setup with a static table view and a slider works well, it takes a minute to build and you can start from there applying your specific features and seeing when it becomes broken. Other than that there's also a responders chain and the actual layout that can be easily verified and the results described at the question.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine I think. 
Also no need to set user interaction.

Here is the example code may you get help form it. It is working fine with autolayout.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *lblTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    lblTitle.text = @"Hi";

    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    slider.value = 0.2;
    slider.tag = indexPath.row;
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderNearbyAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return cell;
}

- (void)sliderNearbyAction:(UISlider *)sender{
    NSLog(@"Slider %ld Value : %.2f",(long)sender.tag, sender.value);
}
```

**OUTPUT with Log :**

[image]

**Autolayout Screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  but can you post the screenshot of the autolayout used in UISlider.

Comment: @Vizllx Sure. Updated.

Comment: @Vizllx Oh! But where is the issue. I think it's constraints issue. Else it is working fine.

Comment: I don't know.. what causing the problem..Layout is working fine.. I guess. I am checking the touch on cell view..

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem was very silly, I have not provided height for cell in different index-path.That's why the  last cell i.e the slider cell was showing but it's height was 30, so  any tap or gesture outside that region was not responding.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue was in `isUserInteractionEnabled`. If you have any interactable elements as subviews of cell (not of contentView), you need to set

```swift
cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

for the cell.